# use conditions inside stream map in my array in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, stream

I am working on a java project where I have to use java stream to collect ids of all the objects inside a list of objects.

Now I only want to collect ids of those objects whose type matches a certain value.

What I am using:

```
List<String> skuGroupIds = skuGroupPagedResponseMap.getData().stream().map(this::getGroupId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now I want to use the condition and I did this but this is giving syntax error:

```
List<String> skuGroupIds = skuGroupPagedResponseMap.getData().stream().map(group->group.getCreatedType().equals(SkuGroupCreationType.SKU_GROUP_LOT)?this::getGroupId:return null;).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`getGroupID function used inside map`

```
private String getGroupId(SkuGroupResponseDTO skuGroupResponseDTO){
    return skuGroupResponseDTO.getSkuId() + Constants.HYPHEN + skuGroupResponseDTO.getId();
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use `filter()` and then `map()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda inside `map()`, should look like this:

```
.map(group -> group.getCreatedType().equals(SkuGroupCreationType.SKU_GROUP_LOT) ? this::getGroupId : null)
```

Or like this:

```
.map(group -> {
    return group.getCreatedType().equals(SkuGroupCreationType.SKU_GROUP_LOT) ? this::getGroupId : null;
})
```

But it would be much better to use a `filter()`, as mentioned in comments:

```
List<String> skuGroupIds = skuGroupPagedResponseMap.getData()
     .stream()
     .filter(group -> group.getCreatedType().equals(SkuGroupCreationType.SKU_GROUP_LOT))
     .map(this::getGroupId)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```